# Email and name fields are blank for some users

Tags: list-manager, goals

Sitecore version: 9.0.2

Issue: Users in the segmented list do not have email and name

What I am doing:
When a user registers on my application, I programmatically trigger the Sitecore provided 'Register' goal.
To send the e-mails, I have created a segmented list. The list is segmented using the out-of-box rule where users have trigged a specific goal in the last 1 day.

In this segmented list, I am finding the user count in list getting updated but the email and name fields are blank for random users. I am getting all the details for a few users.

I am creating contacts using xConnect before triggering the goal.

I am unable to understand this. Please help me to understand the same.

Comment: Have you checked in xDB? Is it saving name and email?

Comment: Can you post your code where you are saving the email address and name details to the Contact Facets?